# Create Custom Mixins in Django

Tags: django

I want to create mixins from normal function.

```
from taggit.models import Tag

def remove_all_tags_without_objects():
    for tag in Tag.objects.all():
        if tag.taggit_taggeditem_items.count() == 0:
            tag.delete()
        else:
            pass
```

I want to convert above function into mixin os i can re use it.

Comment: Why would you want to create a mixin with this function? It doesn't manipulate the object, it just deletes all tags without any associated options. It wouldn't matter if you called this function on itself or as a member of an object.

It is reusable as-is

Comment: I want to use it in the class base views

Comment: You can just do an import for this function and use it as-is, there is no need to make wrap it in a class.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be in a mixin, you just need to wrap it inside a class like:

```
class MyMixin():
    def remove_all_tags_without_objects():
        ...
```

Then you can import it in your views (where `View` is the view class you are using):

```
from path.to.mixin import MyMixin

class MyView(MyMixin, View):
    ...
```

Inside the view you can call this function with `self.remove_all_tags_without_objects()`.